# What is the behaviour of a file-backed memory map when reading from or writing to an address larger than the length of the file?

Tags: kernel, system-calls, documentation, api, mmap

I'm trying to figure out whether it would be undefined behaviour to open a memory map to a file with a very large length. My use-case is that I want to be able to see new data when the file is appended to (via the `write` system call), without using `mremap`. The man page for the `mmap` syscall states that it returns EINVAL if "We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).", but this is obviously very unclear. Specifically, it doesn't explicitly state behaviour when the size of the memory map exceeds the size of the file. When I write a program that opens a memory map of a far larger size than the backing file, writes a value to it and then immediate reads that value back, I see that the `mmap` call doesn't return an error and that the value is actually written to/read from memory correctly. However, the file is not changed. I compiled without optimisations and used a short snippet of inline assembly which does nothing but marks the values in question as clobbered, to prevent this load and store from being optimised out. The man page states that `SIGBUS` should be emitted in this case but as far as I can tell it is not.

While this means that using `mmap` in this way likely works for my usecase of following file changes without recreating the memory map, it does raise the question of whether this works on purpose or whether it works by accident. I don't want to rely on behaviour which is not guaranteed by the Linux kernel, especially when it may cause a critical bug later down the line if information is not correctly synchronised to/from the disk. Is this behaviour defined or guaranteed somewhere?

Comment: "The man page states that SIGBUS should be emitted in this case but as far as I can tell it is not." SIGBUS **will** be emitted, unless your address is within the (rounded-up) last page. Without a reproducible example, it's unclear what you're talking about. Also, I don't get why you can't just grow the file with `ftruncate(2)` to have it back all the mapped area (are you expecting that writing to the mapped area beyond its end will automatically extend it, as with `pwrite(2)`? It won't).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is (hidden) in [the NOTES section of the mmap(2) page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#NOTES):

```
   A file is mapped in multiples of the page size.  For a  file  that
   is not a multiple of the page size, the remaining memory is zeroed
   when mapped, and writes to that region are not written out to  the
   file.
```

But, that text could be a little clearer, and the discussion of `SIGBUS` in the page is not at all clear. I've [changed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/?id=9807d9afdda9e96df4b6410395c4a4106c1e23d2) the above text to read:

```
   A  file  is mapped in multiples of the page size.  For a file that
   is not a multiple of the page size, the  remaining  bytes  in  the
   partial page at the end of the mapping are zeroed when mapped, and
   modifications to that region are not written out to the file.
```

And I've changed the description of `SIGBUS` to read:

```
   SIGBUS Attempted  access  to a page of the buffer that lies beyond
          the end of the mapped file.   For  an  explanation  of  the
          treatment  of the bytes in the page that corresponds to the
          end of a mapped file that is not a  multiple  of  the  page
          size, see NOTES.
```

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is specified, but not in [the Linux `mmap` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), rather [in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html):

> The system shall always zero-fill any partial page at the end of an object. Further, the system shall never write out any modified portions of the last page of an object which are beyond its end. References within the address range starting at *pa* and continuing for *len* bytes to whole pages following the end of an object shall result in delivery of a SIGBUS signal.

If you `mmap` a file with a `MAP_SHARED` mapping larger than the size of the file, and try to write to memory beyond the end of the file, you *are* liable to get a `SIGBUS`, even though the mapping itself covers the range (check `/proc/.../maps`). In the text above, *pa* is the address returned by `mmap`, so what the specification says is that accessing addresses in pages which fall within the mapped area in memory but are entirely beyond the end of the mapped object will result in `SIGBUS`. Reading and writing in a page which is partially within the mapped object works, which corresponds to the protection typically afforded by memory management units.

In addition to that, the behaviour required for your use case is undefined:

> If the size of the mapped file changes after the call to *mmap*() as a result of some other operation on the mapped file, the effect of references to portions of the mapped region that correspond to added or removed portions of the file is unspecified.

There are some additional subtleties related to the page cache on Linux (see [the bugs section in the manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#BUGS)), and those can produce surprising behaviour on top of the above — data written beyond the end of a file but within the last page mapped will not be written to the file, but can survive to subsequent mappings.

`mmap` returns `EINVAL` when mapping a file if the values provided are invalid in general terms, not specifically related to the file being mapped: *i.e.* if the alignment requirements aren’t met, or the offset and length aren’t compatible with the maximum file size the kernel can manage.